# semidirect product problem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I am trying to show that the semidirect product of $G$ with $G$, where $G$ is a finite group, with the automorphism by conjugation on itself, is isomorphic to direct product of $G$ with $G$. Please help

Comment: The two direct factors in $G \rtimes G$ are $\{(g,1) : g \in G \}$ and $\{(g,g^{-1}) : g \in G \}$. Why are you assuming that $G$ is finite? It is true for all groups $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt It makes the problem a little easier/faster because the student can use counting arguments in certain places.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In $G \rtimes G$, we have 
$$
(g_1,g_2)\cdot(h_1,h_2) = (g_1 h_1^{g_2}, g_2 h_2).
$$
Use this operation and the action $h^g=ghg^{-1}$ to prove the following:

Let $H =\{(g, 1) \mid g\in G\} \leq G \rtimes G$. We then have $H \trianglelefteq G \rtimes G$ and $H \cong G$. Next, let $K=\{(g, g^{-1}) \mid g\in G\} \leq G \rtimes G$ and show $K \trianglelefteq G \rtimes G$ and $K \cong G$. Finally, note $H \cap K = 1$ and show that $HK = G \rtimes G$. This gives $G \rtimes G \cong G \times G$ as desired.

Comment: So that, specifically, $(a,b)\mapsto (ab,b^{-1})$ is an isomorphism $G\times G\longrightarrow G\rtimes G$.

Comment: How precisely is $\{(g,g^{-1}\}$ a subgroup? the injection $g\mapsto (g,g^{-1})$ is not a homomorphism, because $(gf,{(gf)}^{-1})\neq (g f^g, g^{-1}f^{-1})$.

Comment: Nevermind, if we take $g\mapsto (g^{-1},g)$ instead, we indeed have a homomorphism.